# Filter list by regexps

Tags: regular-expressions, list, filtering, sequences

How can I get all elements of a list which don't match multiple
patterns?  The patterns are given as a list.

For instance, I want all files without `'("no" "nix")` in them.

```el
(setq se-have
      '("~/site/src/good-org.org"
        "~/site/src/bad-no-org.org"
        "~/site/src/yes-to-org.org"
        "~/site/src/nix-this.org"
        "~/site/src/know-this-will-go.org"
        "~/site/src/is-always-next-to.org"))
```

```el
(setq se-want
      '("~/site/src/good-org.org"
        "~/site/src/yes-to-org.org"
        "~/site/src/is-always-next-to.org"))
```

I can do it for a single pattern:

```el
(seq-filter
 (lambda (x) (not (string-match-p (regexp-quote "no") x)))
 se-have)
```

How could I do this for each pattern in a list?

Comment: Note that `seq-filter` together with a negated `not` predicate is the same as `seq-remove` with the `not` removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're essentially saying you want to match *any* of a list of patterns.

`regexp-opt` takes a list of strings and produces a single regexp which matches any of them.

```
(regexp-opt '("no" "nix"))
=> "\\(?:n\\(?:ix\\|o\\)\\)"
```

Note that the individual strings in the input list are not regexps -- the end result will be analogous to using `regexp-quote` for each string.

The equivalent `rx` syntax is:

```
(rx (or "no" "nix"))
```

Comment: Accepted because it's easy to generalize and works well enough. Unfortunately, it returns `""` when passed `nil` which results in `nil` overall instead of all the files being returned (i.e. no files excluded).  But my users will never use it that way, right? ;)

Comment: if EXCLUSIONS then FILTER LIST else LIST

Comment: Of course! Thank you for the help, again.

Answer (score 4):

```lisp
(seq-filter
 (lambda (x) (and (not (string-match-p (regexp-quote "no") x))
                  (not (string-match-p (regexp-quote "nix") x))))
  se-have)
```

Or use `cl-remove-if-not`. Or use `seq-filter` or `cl-remove-if-not` twice, instead of `and`.  And so on.